# How do I find out which tnsnames.ora file is being used by my linux system?

Tags: linux, oracle

When I do an updatedb and locate tnsnames.ora I get back a long list due to various Oracle DB installations. I need to add some entries to whichever is the "default" tnsnames.ora configured for the system.

How do I find out which of the many tnsnames.ora files is actually being used?

note: none of the 30 odd instances are under any "system" folders (e.g. /etc /usr etc) and:

```
> echo $TNS_ADMIN
TNS_ADMIN: Undefined variable.
> echo $PATH
/usr/kerberos/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/ade/bin:/usr/NX/bin
> echo $ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_HOME: Undefined variable.
```

RHEL4

Answer (score 12):

If **`$TNS_ADMIN`** is not set, then the `tnsnames.ora` should be in **`$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/`**.

You can find more explanations on tnsnames.ora in [Net Services Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14213/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007) book.

To determine the value of `$ORACLE_HOME`, you can look at the file `/etc/oratab`. This file lists database, the associated `$ORACLE_HOME` and if the DB must be started/stopped automatically.

You can also find some informations in the `oraInventory` (have a look at `/etc/oraInventory` folder or `/etc/oraInst.loc` file)

Comment: thanks for the answer but $ORACLE_HOME is also undefined - have amended question.

Comment: ok actually doing a ps -eaf I can see that oracle home is being set by the relevent process... and in fact there is no instance of tnsnames.ora under OH/network/admin so I will create one and try that.

Comment: As said by DCookie, you MUST define ORACLE_HOME to be able to launch Oracle process.

Answer (score 2):

Your output above is from the server that has your Oracle installations? Are you logged in as a user that accesses Oracle? I don't see how you could be getting access to anything Oracle based on that output, unless you do so via shell scripts that build your environment each time. It's been a while, but IIRC on *nix systems you must define ORACLE_HOME in order to access Oracle.

If you type:

```
sqlplus someuser@somedb
```

from the above command prompt, what does it tell you? Seems to me it ought to tell you that sqlplus is an unknown command. If not, what does

```
which sqlplus
```

tell you?

Answer (score 0):

If neither ORACLE_HOME nor TNS_ADMIN are set, try `/etc/tnsnames.ora`